# Applying NativeScript themes to a project downloaded from NativeScript template

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am applying NativeScript themes to a project downloaded from NativeScript template project.

docs [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme) says to place below line in app.css. I did not find direct `app.css` file but `app.android.css` file. Already It has some css code in it and I placed at end of the file.

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/css/core.light.css';
```

When I run tns preview CLI removes newly placed code from `app.android.css` file so I created a new file with `app-common.css` and placed in it.

Now, CLI does not remove it but themes are not visible in mobile app.

How do I link those style sheets to my project?

Comment: Are you using SCSS / SASS in your project, find any files with `.scss` extension? That's is one of the reason I could imagine for `app.android.css` being overridden.

Comment: Yes, moving the @import to app.android.scss file working.